# join multiple tables in sql for stock maintenance application

Tags: sql

The tables are structured with columns as follows:

```
tbl_PIVD = pivID | prodID | Qty |  ScaleID
tbl_GRN = gID | pivID 
tbl_GRND = grndID | gID | prodID | Qty | ScaleID 
tbl_prod = prodID | ScaleID(SIunit)
```

Problem: to get the quantity(Qty) and its difference pending =

```
ConvertScale(tbl_PIVD.Qty, tbl_PIVD.ScaleID, tbl_prodID.ScaleID ) - 
ConvertScale(tbl_GRND.Qty, tbl_GRND.ScaleID, tbl_prodID.ScaleID )
```

from the `tbl_PIVD` and `tbl_GRND` table where `tbl_PIVD.pivID` = `tbl_GRN.pivID` and `tbl_PIVD.prodID` = `tbl_GRND.prodID`.

Subtraction is done after making the both scale equal, scale is converted using a function ConvertScale

how to join the following queries

```
SELECT PID.Qty, GRND.Qty FROM tbl_PIVD PID INNER 
JOIN tbl_GRND GRND on 
PID.prodId = GRND.prodId 


SELECT *  FROM tbl_PIVD PID INNER JOIN 
tbl_GRN GRN ON PID.pivId = GRN.pivID   
GRN.pivID=10609
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following Query will helpful.

```
SELECT ConvertScale(PD.Qty, PD.ScaleID, P.ScaleID) -  
ConvertScale(GD.Qty, GD.ScaleID, P.ScaleID) as 'PendingQty'
FROM tbl_PIVD PD
INNER JOIN tbl_Prod P ON PD.ProdID = P.ProdID
INNER JOIN tbl_GRN G ON PD.pivID = G.pivID
INNER JOIN tbl_GRND GD ON G.gID = GD.gID AND PD.prodID = GD.prodID
```